# Apply Laravel Nova filter to Computed Value

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a Laravel Nova resource, and it has a computed value inside it entitled views. I want to add a Nova filter which can affect the result of the computed value (not the query itself), but can't figure out how to do this.

My computed value looks like this:

```
Text::make('Views', function() {
    return $this->getViewsCount();
}),
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
Text::make('Views', function() {
    if(isset($filterValue)) {
        return $this->getViewsBetween($filterValue);
    } else {
        return $this->getViewsCount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to get the filters value from the request:

```php
$queryFilters = $request->query('filters')
```

The parameter is base64 and json encoded so you'll have to decode it first.
Take a look at `Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\DecodesFilters` as reference.

Your computed field could look something like this:

```php
Text::make('Views', function () use ($request) {

    $queryFilters = $request->query('filters');
    $decodedFilters = collect(json_decode(base64_decode($queryFilters), true));
    $computed = $decodedFilters->map(function ($filter) {
        return $this->getViewsBetween($filter['value']);
    });

    if ($computed->isEmpty()) {
        return $this->getViewsCount();
    }

    return $computed->implode(',');
})
```

Update: `$decodedFilters` holds the class and the value for the selected filters.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "class" => "App\Nova\Filters\UserType"
      "value" => "admin"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do I know which filter I am getting the value of in this? I'm confused. How do I know I'm not getting a different filter?

Comment: @G.S. Good point! You can check for `class` in the `$decodedFilters` collection. I've added the output of the dump-server command to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue about conflict `id` field of filter replaced an model `id` field and `$this->id` in computed field was from another table, not from model. So the solution is to repeat `->select([...])` query (same!) values from model with alias. For example (solving `user.id` field with `userid` alias)

MODEL

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model
{
   //...

   public function scopeMyScope($query, int $userId) : bool
   {
      return $query
            ->select('user.id', 'user.id as userid'/*,...*/)
            ->[...];
   }

   //...
```

FILTER

```
<?php
namespace App\Nova\Filters;


use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Filters\Filter;

class MyFilter extends Filter
{
   //...

   public function apply(Request $request, $query, $value)
   {
        //Same select fields as in model with userid, dont skip select in the filter!
        return $query
            ->select('user.id', 'user.id as userid'/*,...*/)
            ->[...];
   }

   //...
```

RESOURCE

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use App\Nova\Filters\MyFilter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Boolean;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\HasMany;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;

class User extends \App\Nova
{
   //...
   public function fields(Request $request)
   {
      return [
         //userid
         Boolean::make('some', function () {
            return \App\Models\User::myScope($this->userid);
         }),
      ];
   }

   //...
}
```